# sudo apt update: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source

Tags: apt, software-sources, gnupg

This is the error I get when running `sudo apt update`:

```
goutham@goutham-11-11:/$ sudo apt update
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable/ jammy: /usr/share/keyrings/pkgs-osrf-archive-keyring.gpg != /usr/share/keyrings/gazebo-archive-keyring.gpg
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I have no idea what this means. I am very new to Ubuntu, how do fix this issue?

I am using Ubuntu Jammy 22.04. Please guide me through this, step by step, as I am having a difficult time to understand what is going on here in the terminal.